# Is there a configuration parameter that will cause Richfaces 3.3.3 to operate in DEV mode (to unpack js)?

Tags: javascript, richfaces

What I am after is being able to have my application, in dev mode, NOT use the packed javascript libraries.

I have some code that was working and I've changed some things in my app that I'm sure is the source of the problem. However, the javascript error that I'm getting is not helpful:

```
Object required  framework.pack.js.jsf, line 2797 character 1
```

Of course going to that line in the packed source is of no use. I realize that even if it wasn't packed it still may not be that useful to me, but I'd like to be able to make that determination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I asked this question several months ago, but I never found the answer to it and eventually got by the issue I was trying to resolve. Yesterday, I had the same type of thing come up; I'm getting a Javascript error from down in the bowels of the RichFaces Tree scripts and the packed library was of no use in trying to figure out what was going on...so I took up the search again and this time found my answer. So, for anyone else who wants to understand how to get the JavaScript in RichFaces to not be packed there are two configuration settings in your web.xml:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadScriptStrategy</param-name>
  <param-value>DEFAULT</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
  <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.COMPRESS_SCRIPT</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I had tried the last parameter before, but had no luck with it, but didn't realize that the LoadScriptStrategy of "ALL" would cause the COMPRESS_SCRIPT parameter to be ignored.